# can not add new element using ng-repeat in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help. I need to create extra input element using `ng-repeat` in angular.js. I did something but its not working. I explaining my code below.

```
<div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="r in arr">
                <input type="text" ng-model="r.uname"> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<button type="button" id="btn" ng-click="create();">Add</button>
```

Here I need when user will click on add button the new input field will create just below the first one. My scripting side code is given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ContactController($scope){
            $scope.arr=[{uname:null}];
            $scope.create=function(){
                console.log('hii');
                 $scope.arr.push({
                     uname:null
                 });
                 console.log('hi',$scope.arr);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

But here i am unable to generate the new input type element. Please help me.

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: This looks like code which should function fine.  However, in a comment you made to one of the answers, you mention that you are using `angular 1.0.7`.  This is an **ancient** release, and not recommended for any purpose.  If the issues you are having are related to the version of angular you are using, it is *very unlikely* you will ever receive a reasonable answer beyond "update to a newer release" due to the multitude of changes that have been made to angular from the version you are trying to use.

Comment: I therefore voted to close this question as off topic (not reproducible), due to this not being a problem that can be reproduced in a *modern* version of the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an error in your code. it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9536/

```
$scope.arr=[{uname: null}];
  $scope.create = function(){
    console.log('hii');
    $scope.arr.push({
      uname: null
    });
    console.log('hi',$scope.arr);
  }
```

Comment: Check your provided link.

Comment: its working but same thing not working in my side. i am using version 1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Define your array like this..

```
$scope.arr=[{}];
$scope.create=function(){
  $scope.arr.push({});
  console.log('hi',$scope.arr);
}
```

everything else looks fine..

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

Use `track by` in order to achieve the thing you're aiming for:

```
<li ng-repeat="r in arr track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing u are pushing the same element in the array so you want to track the in the ng-repeat

```
    <div ng-repeat="r in arr track by $index">    
   <input type="text" ng-model="r.uname">  </div>
```

still it is not creating then try the console is coming and it is not creating

use  $scope.$apply() to manually run the digest cycle

Answer (score 0):

Which version of angular are you running. The code which you mentioned would not work in angular 1.3 and above. It works in 1.2 though. See this with 1.2

https://plnkr.co/edit/52ygFNbSFZQr3SdCvlDc?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="ContactController">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="r in arr">
            <input type="text" ng-model="r.uname"> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn" ng-click="create();">Add</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function ContactController($scope){
        $scope.arr=[{uname:null}];
        $scope.create=function(){
            console.log('hii');
             $scope.arr.push({
                 uname:null
             });
             console.log('hi',$scope.arr);
        }
    }
</script>
```

For 1.4 and above use the following.    https://plnkr.co/edit/t7STLztqoMiPKaiHr62V?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="ContactController">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="r in arr">
            <input type="text" ng-model="r.uname"> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add

```
app.controller('ContactController', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.arr=[{uname:null}];
        $scope.create=function(){
            console.log('hii');
             $scope.arr.push({
                 uname:null
             });
             console.log('hi',$scope.arr);
        }
});
```